# requestAnimFrame or setInterval for canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Which is the best for canvas animation ? requestAnimFrame or setInterval ?

Comment: `setInterval` is massively quicker. http://jsperf.com/requestanimationframe

Comment: http://jsperf.com/requestanimationframe/3, http://jsperf.com/requestanimationframe/5

Comment: `requestAnimFrame` is *dedicated for animation*. `setInterval` might only be used as a fallback.

Answer (score 6):

`requestAnimationFrame` guarantees that your animation runs exactly when the browser is ready to draw a new frame. If you use `setInterval`, you run the risk of either:

- making the interval too short, in which case you drain battery life performing too-frequent draw operations that will never be displayed
- making the interval too long, in which case you could have gotten a smoother animation by using a shorter interval

`requestAnimationFrame` can throttle to run less frequently when the page is not visible (which can save battery life), but some implementations of `setInterval` do this as well (currently in Firefox and Chrome).

`requestAnimationFrame` is built from the ground up with the intention that it be used for animation; `setInterval` is designed to do anything that requires periodic action. If you are doing animation (especially canvas animation), I would advise using `requestAnimationFrame`, with a fallback to `setInterval` for older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

But you can use setInterval in a big function call i.e. load and call it only when the window is load :

```
function load()
{
   var intervalle = x;
   var game= setInterval(process,intervalle);
   ...

}
window.addEventListener("load",load,true);
```

Comment: -1: How does this answer the question? Yes, you certainly *can* use `setInterval` for animation, but this answer doesn't explain why either `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` is better.